# why my gps is not triggered?

Tags: android

i have a problem with my app getting my GPS position.

first of all i have the two things in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

then i have a code like this for the location:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(0l, 0f, new Criteria(), locationListener, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

now the strange thing:

when i have wifi enabled and i'm in my network, i get a position. If i have only GPS enabled i dont get my position. even i dont see the gps icon at the top of the phone which shows when a app makes use of my gps.

what is wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide more code? For instance, when you call requestLocationUpdates etc etc.

Comment: that will give you coarse location only though, buy try it in order to see if the gps is still working.

Comment: the problem GPS is not working, but over WLAN it works. I would like to have if working over GPS.

Comment: when i use your code i get: The method requestLocationUpdates(String, long, float, LocationListener) in the type LocationManager is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, String, LocationListener)

Comment: Im sorry mate I mean: requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

Comment: this works :) but i need to choose: LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GPS:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

For Network:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```